# multiprocessing.Pool spawning more processes than requested only on Google Cloud

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, multiprocessing

I am using Python's multiprocessing.Pool class to distribute tasks among processes.

The simple case works as expected:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def evaluate:
    do_something()

pool = Pool(processes=N)
for task in tasks:
    pool.apply_async(evaluate, (data,))
```

N processes are spawned, and they continually work through the tasks that I pass into apply_async. Now, I have another case where I have many different very complex objects which each need to do computationally heavy activity. I initially let each object create its own multiprocessing.Pool on demand *at the time it was completing work*, but I eventually ran into OSError for having too many files open, even though I would have assumed that the pools would get garbage collected after use.

At any rate, I decided it would be preferable anyway for each of these complex objects to share the same Pool for computations:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def evaluate:
    do_something()

pool = Pool(processes=N)

class ComplexClass:

    def work:
        for task in tasks:
            self.pool.apply_async(evaluate, (data,))

objects = [ComplexClass() for i in range(50)]

for complex in objects:
    complex.pool = pool


while True:
    for complex in objects:
        complex.work()
```

Now, when I run this on one of my computers (OS X, Python=3.4), it works just as expected. N processes are spawned, and each complex object distributes their tasks among each of them. However, when I ran it on another machine (Google Cloud instance running Ubuntu, Python=3.5), it spawns an enormous number of processes (>> N) and the entire program grinds to a halt due to contention.

If I check the pool for more information:

```
import random
random_object = random.sample(objects, 1)
print (random_object.pool.processes)

>>> N
```

Everything looks correct. But it's clearly not. Any ideas what may be going on?

**UPDATE**

I added some additional logging. I set the pool size to 1 for simplicity. Within the pool, as a task is being completed, I print the current_process() from the multiprocessing module, as well as the pid of the task using os.getpid(). It results in something like this:

```
<ForkProcess(ForkPoolWorker-1, started daemon)>, PID: 5122
<ForkProcess(ForkPoolWorker-1, started daemon)>, PID: 5122
<ForkProcess(ForkPoolWorker-1, started daemon)>, PID: 5122
<ForkProcess(ForkPoolWorker-1, started daemon)>, PID: 5122
...
```

Again, looking at actually activity using htop, I'm seeing many processes (one per object sharing the multiprocessing pool) all consuming CPU cycles as this is happening, resulting in so much OS contention that progress is very slow. 5122 appears to be the parent process.

Comment: you could add a call of `multiprocessing.log_to_stderr(logging.DEBUG)`, more log will be printed to aid debugging.

Comment: @georgexsh I did add this to aid in debugging, but the only output I see it this:

    [DEBUG/MainProcess] starting listener and thread for sending handles
 3537  20   0 3624M  250M 32572 T  0.0  0.4  0:04.35 python ensemble.py                               
[INFO/MainProcess] created temp directory /tmp/pymp-06sjm3do

Comment: I assume you are using the `if __name__ == '__main__':` trick to protect your pool?

Comment: If you are asking if the main pool is being generated in an if __main__ clause, then yes.

Comment: @TSM that's strange, you could add some logs inside of `Pool._repopulate_pool` to see what's happening.

Comment: I've edited the title to try to make it actually reflect the question. A title shouldn't just describe the topic a question is about, but should be reflective of *the specific problem itself*. Thus, instead of saying "strange behavior", it should describe *what* it is that's strange.

Comment: Have you tried using Python 3.5 on OS X to see what happens?

Comment: The last three lines `while True:`... will result in spawning new process until the system resources are exhausted. Does the parent process successfully terminate on OS X?

Comment: Are you sure you're seeing processes and [not threads](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10362/why-does-htop-show-more-process-than-ps)?

Comment: you might be running into odd effects from multiprocess being handled differently in different os.  (https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#contexts-and-start-methods)  if you use `multiprocess.set_start_method` and change it on your computer/the google_cloud computer, can you get them to act the same?

Comment: What does the run time environment use in colab? GPU or CPU?

Answer (score 1):

### 1. Infinite Loop implemented

If you implement an infinite loop, then it will run like an infinite loop. 
Your example (which does not work at all due to other reasons) ...

```
while True:
    for complex in objects:
        complex.work()
```

### 2. Spawn or Fork Processes?

Even though your code above shows only some snippets, you cannot expect the same results on Windows / MacOS on the one hand and Linux on the other. The former spawn processes, the latter fork them. If you use global variables which can have state, you will run into troubles when developing on one environment and running on the other.

Make sure, not to use global statefull variables in your processes. Just pass them explicitly or get rid of them in another way.

### 3. Use a Program, not a Script

Write a program with the minimal requirement to have a `__main__`. Especially, when you use Multiprocessing you need this. Instantiate your Pool in that namespace.

Answer (score 0):

1) Your question contains code which is different from what you run (Code in question has incorrect syntax and cannot be run at all).
2) multiprocessing module is extremely bad in error handling/reporting for errors that happen in workers.
The problem is very likely in code that you don't show. Code you show (if fixed) will just work forever and eat CPU, but it will not cause errors with too many open files or processes.